Is there an adjective that describes something that is characterized by being made of points?
I want to describe a simple diagram which is characterized by having nine points. I want to compare it with a more artistic representation of the same idea.
Is there a word in English that describes something that is characterized by being made of points? I am thinking punctual or punctuated but I'm not sure they can be used this way.
Context
The points of the big Triangle in the punctuated representation...
The first diagram appears, by its punctual simplicity, to be nearer to the Essence.
What do you think?
Here is the image I want to describe.


One well-established term is a point cloud. It is usually encountered in digital image processing and converting from point clouds to surface  or solid representations in computing.

linear.......

Like a dot plot? Depending on the purpose of the representation, there are different technical names for it.

Don't know if it answers the question but pointillism is a technique to create an image from dots. Before dot-matrix or ink-jet printers were invented.

Pointy, depending on the context - it's informal. Otherwise something like angular or jagged if the points are joined by lines. More information would be good.

In design, we would often default to such a pattern as polka dot.

In my opinion, this is a dot matrix representation and not a diagram made of points. I would say that a drawing of a triangle that looks solidly colored is an illustration of all of the points in the triangle, but your drawing is a set of points that alludes to or suggests a triangle without having much to do with the mathematical definition of a triangle. The things you are referring to as points are actually sets of points included in disks, or, in other words, they are dots.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_matrix

These two words seem spot on:
Punctuate  [M-W]: "characterized by dots or points."
Punctiform [M-W]: "marked by or composed of points or dots."
But in real life, I think you can just call it "a dot triangle", "a dot graph", etc.

I would say that the diagram is “plotted out” because I am thinking of coordinates on a graph.
Or you could say it is like a “dot to dot” referring to the drawing game of that name.
